# Properly extend a Widget class using Kotlin

Tags: android, enums, android-widget, kotlin

The code below is basically changing the state of a Button Widget:

```
enum class State {  unable, enable }

fun configureState(currentState:State, button:Button ,colorInt :Int = Color.BLACK) = when (currentState)
{
    State.unable -> {
        button.isClickable = false
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    }

    State.enable -> {
        button.isClickable = true
        button.setBackgroundColor(colorInt)
        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    }
}
```

**The goal is to extend the Button Widget and avoid code repetition inside all my activities.**

Yes it is easy to just extend via function, if I didn't have the `enum State`, by doing something like this:

```
fun Button.configureState(state:Int) = when(state) {
     0 -> {  //do unable stuff  }
     1 -> {  // do enable stuff } 
     else -> { // do nada }
}
```

> My question would be what's the proper way to extend with the enum state where I could access it via Extension Function for example:

```
fun Button.configureWith(state: this.State) = when (state) {
    this.State.unable -> { }
    this.State.enable -> { } 
}
```

P.S again: I'm new to Kotlin :), any ideas .. all welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code treat the `State` as a parameter for changing the button state only. It does not necessary to be declared inside the subclass of Button. You can declare it outside of it with an extension function.

```
enum class ButtonState { unable, enable }

fun Button.configureWith(state: ButtonState, colorInt: Int = Color.BLACK) = when (state) {
    ButtonState.unable -> {
        clickable = false
        setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
    }
    ButtonState.enable -> {
        clickable = true
        setBackgroundColor(colorInt)
    }
}
```